# ASP.NET MVC DataAnnotations doesn't accept dd-MM-yyyy format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, date-formatting

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 project I have a DateOfBirth field that uses the DataAnnotations Validation Date Attribute...

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required"), Date]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

I have set the format of my DatePicker control to dd-MM-yyyy (default was yyyy-MM-dd).
But when I submit the form I am told that the date format is not valid.

dd-MM-yyyy is a valid date format so why would it complain? Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I still get the validation message saying "The value '16-05-2013' is not valid for DateOfBirth. "